# Removing a database unique index constraint in postgres Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

In my Rails `structure.sql`, I have this line of code:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX primary_active_fruit_in_season_constraint ON trees USING btree (user_id) WHERE (is_ripe AND is_in_season);`

I no longer need this validation so I am going to remove the validation in the Rails code on the `Tree` model. But how to I remove this database validation? Where did it come from? What line of code in a rails migration created this? How do I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

We have no way of knowing who created that index but the `WHERE` clause attached to it suggests (since AR generally doesn't know about such advanced things) that it was created manually with something like:

```
connection.execute('create unique index ...')
```

and you can drop the index in a migration the same way:

```
def up
  connection.execute('drop index primary_active_fruit_in_season')
end
def down
  connection.execute('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX primary_active_fruit_in_season_constraint ON trees USING btree (user_id) WHERE (is_ripe AND is_in_season)')
end
```

Manually create a migration file with those two methods in it and `rake db:migrate` as usual.

Comment: Ah I see... I have to use `connection.execute` here. So this is a database-level index with uniqueness right? This isn't a code-based validation of uniqueness?

Comment: Everything in `structure.sql` is inside the database. Unique constraints and unique indexes are, more or less, the same thing. The `WHERE` clause on the index is something ActiveRecord won't understand, that sort of thing is probably why you're using `structure.sql` instead of `schema.rb`.